# How to use flake8 for Python 3 ?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flake8

In this code snippet,

```
def add(x:int, y:int) -> int:
    return x + y
```

there are function annotations that are only supported after python 3.0

When I execute flake8 for this python code:

```
$ flake8 7.3.py -vv
checking 7.3.py
def add(x: int, y: int) -> int:
return x + y
7.3.py:1:11: E901 SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I got the invalid syntax error, but it should be valid syntax. How can I use flake8 to check the syntax that is only supported in Python 3.x?

Comment: See: https://bugs.launchpad.net/pyflakes/+bug/989203

Answer (score 20, accepted):

See: https://bugs.launchpad.net/pyflakes/+bug/989203

**NB:** Whilst this bug report indicates some level of resolution, testing the latest version of pyflakes `0.8.1` this lack of Python 3 Annotations still exists.

I guess you'd have to file a separate new feature request to pyflakes.

[pyflakes Bugs](https://bugs.launchpad.net/pyflakes)

```
$ cat - > foo.py
def add(x:int, y:int) -> int:
    return x + y
^D
$ pyflakes --version
0.8.1

$ pyflakes foo.py
foo.py:1:10: invalid syntax
def add(x:int, y:int) -> int:
         ^
```

**UPDATE** (*20140514*):

As it turns out the actual answer to this problem is to run `pyflakes` or `flake8`
under Python 3.x instead of Python 2.x. It makes sense :)

So do something like this:

```
/usr/bin/python3 -m pyflakes foo.py
```

See: http://codepad.org/9BKxSZaD

Comment: Thanks, I have submitted a bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/pyflakes/+bug/1318497

Comment: I got the feedback from pyflakes. We need to execute pyflakes in Python 3 to rid of that error. That is, pyflakes in python 2 can't be used fro python 3 scripts.

Comment: That actually makes sense! Not sure why I didn't think of that! I'll update the answer to include this! Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

I've got the answer on reddit([here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Atom/comments/4ewro6/how_do_i_get_the_flake8_python_linter_to_use/?st=j3inc6v4&sh=a0cea83b)):

> It uses whatever flake8 is installed in the Python in your path.

so you need to install flake8 by pip3, not pip.

on OSX for me,

```
pip3 install flake8
```

this works for me. :)

Comment: This worked for me too. Also i had to uninstall the homebrew version.

Answer (score 3):

worked for Mac + py2 + py3 + venv:

```
pip install flake8
flake8 --version
3.5.0 (mccabe: 0.6.1, pycodestyle: 2.3.1, pyflakes: 1.5.0) CPython 2.7.14 on Darwin

pip3 install flake8
python3 -m flake8 --version
3.5.0 (mccabe: 0.6.1, pycodestyle: 2.3.1, pyflakes: 1.6.0) CPython 3.6.1 on Darwin
python3 -m flake8 --exclude migrations --max-line-length=121
```

Comment: worked with 
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release: 18.04
Codename: bionic

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure you are using python3's flake8. On linux you'll want to do:

```
sudo pip uninstall flake8
sudo pip3 install flake8
```

Answer (score 0):

Y'all probably should be using [virtual environments](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html) (`python3 -m venv venv; source venv/bin/activate`)... That way, 'python' and 'pip' use the ones you want, by default...  Just saying.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and solved it by installing flake8 through python.

```
$ python --version
Python 3.8.3

$ python -m pip install flake8
```

Comment: this is not a valid answer to this question.

Comment: I have same error as in the original question. I tried an accepted answer and it didn't work. I found installing through python resolved the module version conflict.